# On single gpu, can TensorFlow train a model which larger than GPU memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, gpu, ram

If I have a single GPU with 8GB RAM and I have a TensorFlow model (excluding training/validation data) that is 10GB, can TensorFlow train the model?

If yes, how does TensorFlow do this?

Notes:

1. I'm not looking for distributed GPU training.  I want to know about single GPU case.
2. I'm not concerned about the training/validation data sizes.

Comment: Tensorflow2.0 automatically detects and uses GPU-s if you have appropriate drivers installed. Given that, you also have to use ```tf.data.Dataset``` for the dataset of that size. Tensorflow will  then automatically load chunks of data into GPU memory. Is that what you need?

Comment: @tornikeo no.  I tried to emphasize in my Notes.  I'm not concerned about the data & its size.  I'm interested in the model size (e.g. all the weights, etc.) and what happens if it is larger than GPU RAM.

Comment: My bad. I misread second note. If model does not fit in GPU memory, tensorflow will still train the model, but at a dramatically slower rate, using CPU. You should try to use lower precision, use `tf.float32` or design a smaller model.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not train a model larger than your GPU's memory. (there may be some ways with dropout that I am not aware of but in general it is not advised). Further you would need more memory than even all the parameters you are keeping because your GPU needs to retain the parameters along with the derivatives for each step to do back-prop.

Not to mention the smaller batch size this would require as there is less space left for the dataset.